# Tabular Q-Learning & TicTacToe

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm currently implementing tabular q-learning for 3x3 tictactoe in python
and I'm new to RL and still have a hard time to understand RL.
Therefore, I would like to know one thing:

1. In (tabular) q-learning for tictactoe 3x3 I would like to know in which order the q-value would be added to the state and action pair when I there is only a single episode? Would it be the empty state first or last?:

```
"('_________', 8)": ?,
"('_____O__X', 3)": ?,
"('___X_OO_X', 0)": ?,
"('X__X_OOOX', 1)": ?,
"('XX_XOOOOX', 2)": ?,
```

Comment: Welcome to our community. Can you please reformulate the title as a question and precisely as _specific question_? Thanks